# File Screening on Server Share

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

I am having a bit of a challenge here. I have two file servers configured with DFS enabled. Replication is working just fine and all is well with them. However, I am at a point where I want to do some file screening to prevent users from saving certain file types (FSRM is installed on one server). When I tried to enable file screening on a share eg. `//contoso/public/share` I get an error. The error reads **`The file screen path either is invalid or it doesn't exit.`** Do I have to install FSRM on both servers and do separate file screens or is there a way to enable file screening on shares?

Comment: Knowing the error message would be helpful. Why would you omit that from your question?

Comment: I added the error message to the question just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FSRM will need to point to a local folder, such as E:\Shared\Public not a shared folder.

If these shares are not clustered (e.g. Shared .VHDX file) you'll need to setup the file screening rules on both servers individually.